# wchar_t could not be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, wchar-t

I am developing an Android application which uses JNI and native source code for the implementation. In my C source file I have a variable of the type of `wchar_t*`.

The Eclipse compiler says that the type could not be resolved. I can't find a solution for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an eclipse indexing bug, detailed [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33788).

That page describes some workarounds that you can try...

Its worth noting that this is just an error in the indexing. Your code is likely compiling just fine.

Comment: Thanks. It was a worth a try.